# magento - Why my changes on template files are not showing up

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to add the SKU of the products to the product page by adding the following code:

```
<h3><?php echo $this->__('SKU:') . $this->htmlEscape($_product->getData('sku'));?></h3>
```

I have cleared Magento cache and deleted cache storage. Unfortunately, the changes on template file are not showing up ... any suggestion?

**PHTML file need to be edited**
[image]

**PHTML file edited**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Magento get data directly work like getSku(); Try echo $_product->getSku();